# How to select radio button (or checkbox) in Robot Framework without knowing their exact groupname etc?

Tags: selenium, robotframework

Can I somehow select radiobutton without groupname and value? Eventually I'd like to loop through every clickable element on the page, so I need to click on the first radio button option of the first question etc. Something like:

```
    click element  xpath=//input[@type='radio'][1][1]
```

Comment: in robot framework there is a select radio button function you don;t need do a click: http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Select%20Radio%20Button search for Select Radio Button

Comment: I know, but it needs the group name and value as parameters

Comment: but without none of them the object is not unique because you can have multiple radio button and you are not able to identify which one select

Comment: anyway if you update the ticket with the radio button HADM code maybe I can help u selecting it in a different way but without know the checkbox information is difficult